Unable to Identify Source of Deprecated autoscaling/v2beta2 API Usage in GKE Cluster
I'm currently managing a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud (GKE) and have received a notice that I'm using deprecated APIs which will affect my upgrade to version 1.26. Specifically, the API in question is autoscaling/v2beta2 for HorizontalPodAutoscalers.
Details:
Deprecated API: /apis/autoscaling/v2beta2/horizontalpodautoscalers
UserAgent: v2.6.0
Usages: 27000
Environment:
Kubernetes version: 1.25 (planning to upgrade to 1.26)
GKE cluster on Google Cloud
Helm charts and various third-party tools in use: NGINX Ingress Controller
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
However, I've checked my project thoroughly and I don't use this API directly anywhere. Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Checking all namespaces and resources for references to v2beta2
Reviewing audit logs for deprecated API usage
Ensuring all tools and add-ons are up-to-date
Additional Context:
Checked all HPAs:
kubectl get hpa --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.apiVersion}{"\n"}{end}'
Output:
ingress-nginx-controller    autoscaling/v2
Queried Audit Logs:
Used the Logs Explorer in Google Cloud Console with the following filter:
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
jsonPayload.apiVersion="autoscaling/v2beta2"
Used gcloud CLI to read logs:
gcloud logging read "resource.type=k8s_cluster AND jsonPayload.apiVersion=\"autoscaling/v2beta2\"" --limit 100 --format json
Both methods returned no relevant logs.
Checked for Third-Party Tools and Add-ons:
Ensured that all third-party tools, Helm charts, and operators are up-to-date.
Searched for Deprecated API Usage:
Ran a raw API call:
kubectl get --raw /apis/autoscaling/v2beta2/horizontalpodautoscalers | jq .
This also returned no results.
Despite these efforts, I'm still receiving notices about the deprecated API usage. Is there something I might be missing or another way to track down where these API calls are coming from? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Your investigation seems comprehensive. Does your gcloud logging read statement return any values? I would expect the Kubernetes methods to appears as protoPayload.methodName and, in this case, have a value =~"io.k8s.autoscaling.v2beta2". However, your kubectl commands should provide equivalent data.

Did you see this question which shares similarities?
